# .htaccess holding page without changing site URL

Tags: .htaccess

If I have a site `mysite.com` and in the root of the site I have a /holding/index.html file, how can I write my .htaccess to show the index of the holding page without showing the URL `mysite.com/holding/` in the address bar.

Here is my directory structure:

```
public_html
└── .htaccess
└── holding
    └── index.html
    └── assets (css, img)
└── email-signature
    └── assets (img)
```

My .htaccess is currently:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/email-signature/assets/logo.jpg$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/email-signature/assets/spacer.gif$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/holding/(.)*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /holding/ [R=302,L]
```

But this shows `mysite.com/holding/` in the address bar ... I want it to stay as `mysite.com` but still show the holding page index. Is this possible?

The email signature assets need to be accessible at `mysite.com/email-signature/assets/...` (I'd also like to not have to specify each file in the .htaccess but just wildcard all jpg,png,gif files in `email-signature/*` as accessible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove `R=302` and clear browser cache

Comment: @anubhava that has helped, the page is showing now, but I can't use relative paths ("dist/css/styles.css") to reference my assets in my html so the stylesheet and images are broken. Any round this without having to write "http://example.com/holding/dist/css/styles.css" to retrieve css file correctly?

Comment: For that add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Nice, thanks. Although I had to set it to `<base href="/holding/" />`

Comment: About the close reason: As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283057/mod-rewrite-questions-getting-migrated-to-sf) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283033/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so) this question is not at all off-topic for SO so close vote is wrong. This has been discussed again and again and it has been settled already that most of the rewrite rules are created and maintained by developers of the web applications/frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/email-signature/ [NC]
RewriteRule !^holding/ /holding/ [NC,L]
```

- Remove `R=3xx` flag to avoid external redirect
- Add this just below  section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/holding/" />` to resolve relative paths of css/js/images etc.